# Dagger 2: How to inject an object created within a @Provides method?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I've got this:

**Bike.java**

```
public class Bike {
    String serial;

    @Inject
    Wheels wheels;

    public Bike(String serial) {
        this.serial = serial;
    }
}
```

**BikeModule.java**

```
@Module
public class BikeModule {
    @Provides
    public Bike provideBike() {
        return new Bike("BIK-001");
    }

    @Provides
    public Wheels provideWheels() {
        return new Wheels("WLS-027");
    }
}
```

**BikeComponent.java**

```
@Component(modules = BikeModule.class)
public interface BikeComponent {
    Bike bike();
}
```

Now here's the problem: when I call `BikeComponent.bike()`, I get a bike with the serial `BIK-001`, as intended, but the wheels are not injected. However, if I annotate the `Bike` constructor with `@Inject` and remove the `BikeModule.provideBike()` method, the wheels *do* get injected. So the problem seems to be about injecting an object created within a `@Provides` method, instead of created by Dagger itself.

Is there a way to tell Dagger to inject a provided object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite like this:

```
public class Bike {

    private final String serial;
    private final Wheels wheels;

    @Inject
    public Bike(String serial, Wheels wheels) {
        this.serial = serial;
        this.wheels = wheels;
    }
}

@Module
public final class BikeModule {

    @Provides
    public static Bike provideBike(Wheels wheels) {
        return new Bike("BIK-001", wheels);
    }

    @Provides
    public static Wheels provideWheels() {
        return new Wheels("WLS-027");
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! What I was trying to do was to mix constructor and field injection. Maybe there's no way to do it.

Comment: You could with guice, so I believe you can in dagger also, but I would advise against it. Stick to basic features of dependency injection if you want a nice experience with the pattern (constructor injections only, with providers for factories).

Comment: If you don't want to change your constructor, you can do it like 
@Provides
    public static Bike provideBike(Wheels wheels) {
        Bike bike = new Bike("BIK-001");
        bike.setWheels(wheels);
        return bike;
    }

If you wish to use '@Inject' for Wheels, you have to inject your Bike object through your component. That's how field injection works.

Comment: Just a detail: you can remove the @Inject annotation from the Bike constructor because you're providing an instance yourself.